# How can I make 'white border transitions and image zoom up' when hover over image

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to add a custom hover just like the project tiles on https://ueno.co/ whereby on hover a white border transitions up, and the image zooms up too. Here is a link to my homepage, it is the Portfolio grid I am trying to improve - http://www.david-healey.com/

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2:**

You can use below example on your website. Just add Class: `zoomimg` to the image structure.

```css
.menu{
  text-align:center;
}

.zoomimg {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    position: relative;
}
.zoomimg:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-size: 150% 150%;
    transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    height: 150.797px;
    width: 150.984px;
}
.blog {
     background-image: url(http://www.david-healey.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/ST_Project_Thumb_570%C3%97587.jpg);
    display: block; 
    top: 65.0938px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
    <div class="blog zoomimg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Pratik. Thats awesome! Any ideas how Ueno added the white border on hover too please? https://ueno.co/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to scale `img` up and scale `.thumb-inner` down.

```css
.thumb-inner {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.thumb-inner,
.thumb-inner img {
  transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
}

  .thumb-inner:hover {
    transform: scale(.97);
  }

  .thumb-inner img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <div class="thumb-inner">
    <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dvjpaoffl/image/upload/v1486268758/sample.jpg">
  </div>
</a>
```